# How to do multiple Task in asp.net web service?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, linq-to-sql

I have my own web service which service i am calling using jquery ajax post method.In this Method I am doing few things which is taking too much time.

These are the calls which i am doing.

1. Calling a API.
2. Based on the response checking a table's record and inserting the data to the table.
3. Checking records to another table and inserting to records another table.
4. Return API response to page back.

And this return approx 100 records in one API call.

Right now i am processing these steps 100 times, which is taking too much execution time. I want to make these things like that so it can take less time for execution.

What will be the best steps that i need to follow.

Comment: Did you try to use Parallel?

Comment: If you will post your processing code snippet this will help. Thank you